# Changing all Web Reference Url's in Visual Studio Solution , Possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with many projects in it.

these projects all consume some Web-Services so all of them have References to some Web Url.

When I switch from Server to Server , I need to change all of these Url's.

I Know how to dynamically change Web References in final App, but keep in mind that these Web Services are in development environment , so are modified as a daily basis and it is hard to 
change their Reference Url one-by-one in solution.

Is there a way to change all Solution's Web Reference Url's together ?

Regards, Saeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a DLL that provides the URL and all the projects access that DLL to get the URL. That way only one file needs changing.

The URL could be provided via an environment variable, or a file in a defined directory, that each project reads when it starts.

The above two ideas might be combined. Have a DLL that reads the URL from a somewhere and provides it to the calling project. A clever DLL might know the difference between the machines that execute the tests and choose an appropriate URL.

There is also the Visual Studio editor, using menu => **Edit** => **Find and replace** => **Replace in files**.

Comment: using environment variables and dll will be the way to make url dynamic. but this is not the case.
using Find and Replece in Reference.map files , I changed all Reference url's but this also seems not working.

Comment: @SaeedMousavi I do not understand your comment. What "*is not the case*" and what "*seems* [to be] *not working*"? Please add more details to your question (but not here as a comment) to explain what you are trying to do, to explain what you have already tried, and to explain why those attempts were not satisfactory.